# mvc3 model bind to multiple lists of the same type

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, list, razor, model-binding

suppose...

in the razor view we have a model of Object A

```
@Model Object A
```

Object A is an instance of class A, which has multiple instances of Class B, which have a list of type C

```
Class A
public B Object1
public B Object2

Class B
public List<C> List1
```

There is an EditorView for Object B. There is a larger view for Object A in which each object B use an object B EditorView.

```
 @Model Object B

 ...do things with list in object B
```

So, when the view renders, there are multiple Editor Views of class B present. What code can I use in the editorview to add additional C to the list List1 in B Object1 without affecting the list List1 in B Object2.

```
 @Model Object B

 ... would like to add to this list and have it post back, and only effect the b it in. I don't know how to reference this object's master to add to this list exculsively
```

I looked at http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx a few times. Its like having multiple...

```
<input type="text" name="[0].Title" value="Curious George" />
<input type="text" name="[0].Author" value="H.A. Rey" />
<input type="text" name="[0].DatePublished" value="2/23/1973" />

<input type="text" name="[0].Title" value="Curious George" />
<input type="text" name="[0].Author" value="H.A. Rey" />
<input type="text" name="[0].DatePublished" value="2/23/1973" />
```

on the same page and wanting them to post back to their correct masters on the postback. Thats what I want to do. I want to dynamically add

```
<input type="text" name="...." value=""/>
```

but I'm running into problems with what do I put in the name spot to make it happen. Doing the @Html.EditorFor, and @Html.HiddenFor seem to work in that they modelbind to the correct parent, but they do not allow me to add additional input to the list.

My intuition direction - do something with reflection (or not) to get the name of the object of the master, use this to create a proper name?

Ideas or Code samples please. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Html.EditorFor should give you the format to use. They need to be sequential and you'll need to either count the existing items (-1) to get your new [x] index to use in the name or parse the last elements name using a regex or string parse and extract its index, assuming you are allowing gaps in the sequence, which means you'll also need a custom binder if you want gaps.

Answer (score 0):

okay, solution may be to use the editorfor a different variable to get the general name of the parent variable, and use jquery/js to parse this name and then dynamically insert the input type=file with a name based on this.